# How can I join two RDD's in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I need to join two RDD's in PySpark but I'm having some trouble, here are what the RDD's look like:

```
rdd1:
+------+---+---+
|    _1| _2| _3|
+------+---+---+
|Python| 36| 10|
|     C|  6|  1|
|    C#|  8|  1|
+------+---+---+

rdd2:
+------+---+
|    _1| _2|
+------+---+
|Python|  8|
|     C| 15|
|    C#|100|
+------+---+
```

After joining them, here is the result I need:

```
+------+---+---+---+
|    _1| _2| _3| _3|
+------+---+---+---+
|Python| 36| 10|  8|
|     C|  6|  1| 15|
|    C#|  8|  1|100|
+------+---+---+---+
```

If anyone know how to do this it would be greatly appreciated, I've been able to append a 2 column RDD with another 2 column RDD, but the same method won't work for what I need here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "wrap" your 36, 10 into a tuple and use it to join with the new rdd

```py
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([('python', 36), ('c', 6), ('c#', 8)])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([('python', 10), ('c', 1), ('c#', 1)])
rdd3 = sc.parallelize([('python', 8) , ('c', 5), ('c#', 100)])

# this is the 1st joined rdd
rdd12 = rdd1.join(rdd2).map(lambda x: (x[0], *x[1]))

# this is the 2nd join
rdd123 = (rdd12
    .map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1], x[2])))
    .join(rdd3)
    .map(lambda x: (x[0], *x[1][0], x[1][1]))
)

# [('python', 36, 10, 8), ('c#', 8, 1, 100), ('c', 6, 1, 5)]
```